# axios dynamic URL doesn't work with put request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

this works:

```
https://api.printful.com/orders/92778df366
```

but this doesn't:

```
https://api.printful.com/orders/${id}
```

the only difference is once is dynamic one is not I even tried this :

```
console.log(`https://api.printful.com/orders/${id}`===`https://api.printful.com/orders/9259hgj3887`)
```

and it says true so I guess some problem with axios?

So this works:

```
axios.put("https://api.printful.com/orders/92778jhg3d66",
            request
              ,{
      headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          "X-PF-Store-Id":"sdfdsf"
    },
```

this doesn't:

```
axios.put(`https://api.printful.com/orders/${id}`,
            request
              ,{
      headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          "X-PF-Store-Id":"sdfdsf"
    },
```

Comment: try `const url = \`your template\`` and use `axios.put(url, ...)` and `console.log(url)` each time. if they are both the same you have some sort of other problem, like a whitespace issue. `console.log(url.length)` for both and see if there's a difference :)

Comment: nope it happening with every function when console.log length its equal and the url is exactly the same just when i change to dynamic url server responds with 400